# Why is crossorigin attribute necessary to load images into a canvas and render it?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, cors, frontend, same-origin-policy

When loading an `Image` via setting the `src` attribute to the URL into a `Canvas` and trying to call `toDataURL()` on the canvas, this will only be allowed when the `crossorigin` attribute is set before loading the `Image`.

Why is this though? If the image has the proper `Allow-Access-Control-Origin` header. Is it because the `Origin` attribute is not used when loading an `Image` via a URL (i.e. the `Origin` header is only included when the `crossorigin` attribute is set)?

Comment: from the MDN documentation - *This tells the browser to request cross-origin access when trying to download the image data* - though that documentation does not go into much detail, does it matter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336789/purpose-of-the-crossorigin-attribute

Comment: @JaromandaX it matters for my understanding. :)

Comment: the attribute tells the browser whether to use a cross origin request, and what headers to expect.  such as sending credentials.  yes, the origins header is part of it.

Comment: @AdamThompson - all good - I should've linked to the documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image - you may find something there that I did not :p

Comment: Yes,`img` element `src` URL requests only send `Origin` headers if a `crossorigin` attribute is set. That comes from https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-list-of-available-images:cors-settings-attribute and https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#create-a-potential-cors-request; *corsAttributeState* only ends up being `cors` if a `crossorigin` attribute is set. That leads to https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode, where a COR request is created only if the mode is `cors`. Then to https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-request, “A CORS request is an HTTP request that includes an `Origin` header”.

Comment: @slideshowbarker very nice answer - love your approach of solving the problem! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being that images are commonly used to load arbitrary user-defined content, and image data just opens up another vector that could be for example used to hide executable code that can be decoded later to bypass XSS filters.  And ImageData and OffscreenCanvas can be passed across frames and to workers.
And there really aren't any valid use cases for allowing arbitrary image data from an element be retrieved without it being explicitly requested for, with a simple attribute.  (Especially when it can just be rendered)
I think the question should be, why should it be allowed by default?

Not to mention the overhead of keeping a paper-trail for cors whitelisted (untainted) resources, when you can just have them blacklisted by default.

---

Basically tells the browser whether it should use a CORS request, and what headers to expect.  Specifically whether to send and expect credentials.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-crossorigin

**crossorigin**
Indicates if the fetching of the image must be done using CORS. CORS-enabled images can be reused in the  element without being "tainted." Allowed values:

**anonymous**
A cross-origin request (i.e., with Origin HTTP header) is performed, but no credentials are sent (i.e., no cookie, X.509 certificate, or HTTP Basic authentication). If the server does not give credentials to the origin site (by not setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP header), the image will be tainted and its usage restricted.

**use-credentials**
A cross-origin request (i.e., ***with the Origin HTTP header***) performed **along with credentials sent (i.e., a cookie, certificate, or HTTP Basic authentication)**. ***If the server does not give credentials to the origin site (through the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials HTTP header), the image will be tainted and its usage restricted.***

***If the attribute is not present, the resource is fetched without a CORS request*** (i.e., ***without sending the Origin HTTP header***), preventing its non-tainted usage in  elements. If an invalid value, it is handled as if the anonymous value was used. See CORS settings attributes for additional information.