# Angular cross origin build option

Tags: json, angular, typescript, web

I would like to build my angular application with the cross origin build option. I am currently using a couple of build options and it works fine (prod and output-hashing). When I attempt to add cross-origin build option in the command line I get the following error: **Unknown option --cross-origin** (or --crossOrigin depending on how I write it so it is not a case convention issue). If add the the crossOrigin option to the angular.json file under the projects architect build options section then I get the following error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(crossOrigin).
I would like to know what is causing this error and how to overcome it.

Comment: Why.... do you think this is even an option..? And what do you expect it to do..?

Comment: @MikeOne it will allow you to set the different values of your cross origin options https://angular.io/cli/build#options.

Comment: Right, never heard of that one . So this will only fix very specific scenario’s right (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336789/purpose-of-the-crossorigin-attribute)? What Angular version are you using?

Comment: Angular version 7

Comment: Right.. it seems that option flag was added in v8.1..

Comment: Do we have any evidence for that? How do we manipulate CORS behavior in Angular now?

Comment: What exactly do you want? This will not fix cors issues with the http client.. (see SO link I posted earlier). Evidence: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14743

Comment: I have ajax calls that are working in IE but are throwing CORS errors in Chrome. I am using Windows authentication.

Comment: Rule of thumb.. CORS issues can ONLY be solved server side. Does the server return CORS headers?

Comment: If it works in IE that means the server setting as it relates to CORS is correct. The issue here is the harsh Chrome security restriction.

Comment: Chrome is fine really. IE’s CORS implementation is broken in some versions. Can you show the headers returned? And the exact error you’re seeing?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'web url1' from origin 'web url 2' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Chrome prompts for credentials when IE does not.

Comment: The error is pretty clear..? Bottom line, there is nothing you can do in Angular to fix a CORS issue (unless the issue is related to something like an unexpected redirect or something). Your server needs to respond with the correct headers.

Comment: My point is the same server responds to IE, and I build an aspx page with JQuery that responds to Chrome fine.

Comment: Yeah.. that doesn’t sounds like cross origin. I don’t hink I can help you any further. Good luck with this.

Comment: The `crossOrigin` option is somewhat niche (in terms of what it applies to) from what I understand. For people to further help, please add some info on how you send the requests (and maybe an example of the request and response headers, also in comparison to those jquery requests you mentioned).

Comment: @GunnarB I am just making a GET ajax call. It works in IE but I have the above mentioned CORS issue in Chrome.