# Error on line 0. Google jquery api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, same-origin-policy

Since yesterday I have a strange error on `line 0` in `"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"` (Google jQuery Api). It just says "Script Error". I have researched about the error, but I just found [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913978/cryptic-script-error-reported-in-javascript-in-chrome-and-firefox). I dont think Google forbid Same-origin policy access.

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this error?

I get this Error in Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

**edit:**

I monitor the error messages with the help of

```
window.onerror = function (text, file, line) {
}
```

Comment: try this link - `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js`

Comment: try removing `https://` this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that a Problem at the google Hosted jQuery File occured, which you examine with `window.onerror`. When you want to see a correct Error, download the Library and use a internal link to the Library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//your.site.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

If this dont fix the Error, use the `non-minified` Version to determine the Error.