# Do I need to take action on Facebook Connect script errors?

Tags: javascript, facebook, error-logging

I have JS exception logging so I can see all the JS exceptions that are being thrown on my clients.

Very often I come across these:

```
Script error
http://connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js:0
```

or just `Script Error on line 0` (most likely also triggered by FB)

Anyway, my exception logs are cluttered by these exceptions, so I'm wondering:

- Is there anything that I can do to prevent these specific errors?
- Do the end users have active problems when these errors occur, or is this an uncritical script error on Facebooks part?
- Is it wise to set them to *ignore* in my exception logger?

The errors seem to come and go pretty random, without me taking any action, but still it feels freaky to start ignoring these exceptions.

Comment: Please add more code if you want us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

I've also seen this for facebook. As I understand it, this is not a Facebook specific error - it's an origin policy error. This may occur when people visit your site without having facebook cookies, for instance (something that should be quite common and normal). This is code beyond your control - feel free to ignore the warnings being raised.

See more discussion at this excellent stack overflow post: [Cryptic "Script Error." reported in Javascript in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913978/cryptic-script-error-reported-in-javascript-in-chrome-and-firefox).

Comment: Thanks, following up: can I safely ignore this error forever, or could it be that there is any action that I need to take? I.e. could this also happen when I haven't upgraded through the latest SDK, or whatever?

Comment: It's weird anyway that there are errors popping up in there scripts if there are no problems. You would expect they would have handled all the errors gracefully.