# strange double window.onerror behaviour

Tags: javascript, html

I have two test files, `test1.html` and `test2.html`. I have `test1.html` as follows:

```
<script>
window.onerror = function (message, file, lineNumber, columnNumber, error) {
    console.log(message, file, lineNumber, columnNumber, error);
};

asdf // Trigger error
</script>
```

which prints (as expected)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: asdf is not defined file:///Users/justin/Desktop/test1.html 6 1 ReferenceError: asdf is not defined(…)
```

I have `test2.html` as follows:

```
<script src='test.js'></script>
```

where `test.js` is:

```
window.onerror = function (message, file, lineNumber, columnNumber, error) {
    console.log(message, file, lineNumber, columnNumber, error);
};

asdf
```

which prints (not as expected)

```
Script error.  0 0 null
```

How can I catch the error information when my script is included using `src='test.js'` instead of inline?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913978/cryptic-script-error-reported-in-javascript-in-chrome-and-firefox (the answer suggests: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-crossorigin)

Comment: I am doing this locally, and the `crossorigin` attribute gives me the error `Script from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: I am loading the scripts locally inside a `WKWebView`, so there's no web server for me, even in production.

Comment: or try: let the server return a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin = null' header.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7348

Comment: I'm not using Cordova. I'm using my own instance of `WKWebView` without server.

Comment: Cordova uses an embedded webserver:
    // Note: the embedded webserver is still needed for iOS 9. It's not needed to load index.html,
    //       but we need it to ajax-load files (file:// protocol has no origin, leading to CORS issues).
    NSString *directoryPath = myMainViewController.wwwFolderName;

https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView/blob/4f83a17a3e0cdecbe4cd2d2801625ab415aaa55f/src/ios/AppDelegate%2BWKWebViewPolyfill.m

Answer (score 0):

I did not use the `window.onerror` but it did show the same error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: asdf is not defined

```
try {
    asdf // Trigger error
} catch (e) {
    function test (message, file, lineNumber, columnNumber, error){
        console.log(message, file, lineNumber, columnNumber, error);
    };

    test(e);
}
```

Comment: Didn't you want to get the same error when using `src='test.js'`?

Comment: I want to get all errors. `test.js` was just an example to demonstrate