# "Script error" on IndexedDB with window.onerror()

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, nw.js, dexie

I develop a nw.js app. I try to save javascript errors to indexedDB (via Dexie.js) but I only see `"Script error"` instead of full details I get with `window.onerror()` function.

Here is related part of my code:

```
window.onerror = (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => {
    spawn(function* () {
      db.errors.add({
        source: source,
        message: message,
        lineno: lineno,
        colno: colno,
        error: error,
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913978/cryptic-script-error-reported-in-javascript-in-chrome-and-firefox does this help

Comment: There is no cross-origin. My database is local.

Comment: weird... im afraid i can't help you but hopefully someone who knows dexie is able to

Comment: Is your javascript code inside the .html file?

Comment: No. It's in external .js file.