# Google Maps Javascript crossorigin script tag support

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cross-domain

I'm trying to get all my application's error reported back to me using the window.onerror handler. This works perfectly for the scripts that are in my domain but it does not for the ones loaded from CDNs since it will report the cryptic error exposed here:
[Cryptic "Script Error." reported in Javascript in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913978/cryptic-script-error-reported-in-javascript-in-chrome-and-firefox)

And as stated in this post you can get a full cross-domain error reporting using the crossorigin attribute for the script, but ow surprise! apparently, Google maps even when they basically force you with their business model to do cross-domain scripting they don't provide (at least out of the box) support for subresource integrity. read more about this here: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity)

My question is: is there a way to configure Google maps may be from the Google Console to return the appropriate 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header so I can have proper error reporting? If not I think as a forced CDN Google should consider adding support for this.

I'm showing here a small HTML example that illustrates the issue. With the crossorigin attribute applied you will get a nice message but since Google servers are not properly configured this does not work. And without it in the window.onerror you will get 0 information.

```
 <html>
 <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       window.onerror = function (msg, url, line, column, error) {
                console.log(`There was an error with message:${msg} in the url: ${url} line ${line} column ${column} with error ${error}`);
                //Here we will call our server with the proper error information.
            };
     </script>

  <!-- try using the first one and you will notice that the error message that we get in the onerror callback is useless -->
  <!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script> -->


  <!-- try using the second one and you will notice that there is an error in the console -> Access to Script at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.-->
  <!-- This error indicates a bad configuration on Google servers that are not returning a valid 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
```