Why does `window.addEventListener("error", ...)` sometimes give "Script error." with no other details?
(I initially thought this was just a Chrome bug, but I've tested in Firefox and it has similar weird behavior, and even uses the exact same "Script error." string in the event.message, so I'm wondering whether this is a spec-related issue.)
My intuition with the code below is of course that each of the tests (where I purposely input an invalid value into a constructor) should produce the same ErrorEvent (just with different line numbers and stuff) in the window.addEventListener("error", ...) handler, but as noted in the comments of this code block, they produce different behavior.
<script>
  window.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
    console.error("window error handler:", e);
  })
</script>

<!-- Note: This is just an immutable snapshot of https://codemirror.net/codemirror.js and note that the txt extension doesn't affect this issue - it occurs with js extension too. The txt was just because github doesn't allow uploading js files. -->
<script src="https://github.com/user-attachments/files/17729754/codemirror6-november-13-2024.txt"></script>

<script>
  let { EditorView } = CM["@codemirror/view"];
</script>

<script>
  new EditorView(null); // Example 1: just "Script error."
</script>

<script type="module">
  new EditorView(null); // Example 2: just "Script error."
</script>

<script type="module">
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10));
  new EditorView(null); // Example 3: just "Script error."
</script>

<script>
  (async function() {
    new EditorView(null); // Example 4: no window error event at all??
  })();
</script>

<script type="module">
  let { EditorView } = await import("https://esm.sh/@codemirror/view@6.4.1");
  new EditorView(null); // Example 5: ✅ produces error event with the actual error attached 
</script>


<!-- note: this uses a data url, but i tested using an actual server to server this file and it's the same result -->
<script src="data:text/plain,window.foo=function(a){a.b.c}"></script>
<script>
  foo(1); // Example 6: ✅ produces error event with the actual error attached 
  // caveat: in firefox, specifically, this data URL version gives "Script error.", but substituting it with a server url version results in the same behavior as chrome.
  // chrome gives the 'correct' behavior for both cases.
</script>

Notes:

I initially thought it had something to do with module scripts, but the last example shows that's not the cause.
I thought maybe Example 4 had something to do with needing a window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", ...) handler, but I tried that and it didn't receive any events.
The ErrorEvent also includes the filename property, which gives the script that caused it (but includes no line number, stack, etc.)

Extra Context:
I'm building a developer tool which hooks into the error events on the page to help the developer understand the cause/source of the error. I don't control the code on the page, so I need to be able to get the error details without re-writing the code.
Hence "you could just avoid writing your code/imports in XYZ form" is unfortunately not a solution for me.
Addendum:
(Bolding is for skimming, not shouting.)

This SO question/answer seems to suggest that it's due to a security consideration when loading cross-domain scripts. But, strangely, @KLASANGUI's answer shows that the error messages can be accessed if the defer attribute is added to the script even though the github.com script in my example doesn't have the appropriate CORS headers (so it can't be that defer just uses crossorigin by default).


@johnnyaug Nah, this is wrong, you can get everything... See my answer below with working example.

@joe Note that in my answer below, almost all the scripts throw error because they're trying to access CM which is not accessible (yet). You must wait for the script that defines CM to fully load before you trigger those errors more precisely.

Please, note that you must attach the event listeners before any other script runs, defer the others scripts so they run after the initializer (not in parallel).
Also, note that error events have error objects that are the original error (with the proper stack if available).
See that in the example below there's no "Script error" and every "Error Object" have a stack.


<script>
  // Just clearing the console of snippet errors
  // at each run.
  console.clear();
  
  window.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
    // CORS issue might happen here because the
    // console is overwritten in the snippet and
    // can't access some properties of the event.
    // Do not send to console directly in the snippet.
    console.warn("window error handler:", e.message ?? e.error.message);
    // Also, I changed from `.error()` to `.warn()`
    // just for differentiation at the console.
    // Warnings are yellow, errors are red.
  })
</script>

<!-- CHANGE: The `defer` attribute is added to this script. -->
<script src="https://github.com/user-attachments/files/17729754/codemirror6-november-13-2024.txt" defer></script>

<script>
  let { EditorView } = CM["@codemirror/view"];
</script>

<script>
  new EditorView(null); // Example 1: just "Script error."
</script>

<script type="module">
  new EditorView(null); // Example 2: just "Script error."
</script>

<script type="module">
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10));
  new EditorView(null); // Example 3: just "Script error."
</script>

<script>
  (async function() {
    new EditorView(null); // Example 4: no window error event at all??
  })();
</script>

<script type="module">
  let { EditorView } = await import("https://esm.sh/@codemirror/view@6.4.1");
  new EditorView(null); // Example 5: ✅ produces error event with the actual error attached 
</script>


<!-- note: this uses a data url, but i tested using an actual server to server this file and it's the same result -->
<script src="data:text/plain,window.foo=function(a){a.b.c}" defer></script>
<script>
  foo(1); // Example 6: ✅ produces error event with the actual error attached 
  // caveat: in firefox, specifically, this data URL version gives "Script error.", but substituting it with a server url version results in the same behavior as chrome.
  // chrome gives the 'correct' behavior for both cases.
</script>




Oh, that's very strange. According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913978/cryptic-script-error-reported-in-javascript-in-chrome-and-firefox (which was linked in an earlier comment by another user which has since been deleted), it's a security-related thing that has been around for a long time. So I wonder if you've found a bug, or if defer adds crossorigin by default (that would be strange, so I doubt it). If the explanation where just "you need crossorigin for security reasons" then I'd consider this solved, but now I'm just more confused ^^'

Also, note due to the details in 'Extra Context' in my post, I can't edit the document to add defer, since it would break some the 'userland' code. But it looks like I'm asking for the impossible here, if this is indeed security-related (but your answer suggests it's not...). I gave a +1 in any case.

@joe Oh, I saw that other post... But it is very outdated. I don't really know what is the environment of your DevTool (if it is an extension over a browser, a standalone application, etc.). Depending on the environment, you should have an option to run a custom script/callback before any other script runs on the document. Also, there's almost no more CORS issues when catching unhandled errors. I think you can attach an error event handler to an (i)frame or popup window then load the desired document/address there after the listener is attached.
